# How to make a make Bootstrap 4 slide in menu push content offcanvas?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to make a right to left slide in menu, that also when it slides in pushes the content of canvas. How can I do this?

Here's the code. It slides the menu from right to left on mobile, but I cannot figure out how to make it push the content too, and not be buggy.

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    position: absolute;
    top: 54px;
    left: 1%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapsing {
    height: auto !important;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    left: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.show {
    left: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Brand</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse bg-dark" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec tempor dolor, ut varius magna. Cras a dui vitae massa interdum varius. Donec sit amet risus ullamcorper, congue purus nec, vulputate nunc. Integer cursus molestie metus, sit amet rutrum
  est feugiat vel. Praesent congue turpis a ullamcorper mattis. In commodo, mi convallis tristique vestibulum, massa lacus efficitur tortor, accumsan vehicula nunc ipsum id metus. Aenean vulputate nulla aliquet diam auctor, in tristique augue efficitur.
  Cras accumsan est nisi, vitae consectetur eros egestas ac. Vestibulum id imperdiet odio, in pellentesque nunc. Duis nunc lorem, sollicitudin nec mauris a, consequat posuere tellus. Nam in lobortis arcu. Suspendisse sodales aliquet tempus. Nam ut libero
  iaculis risus laoreet tincidunt. Pellentesque sodales nibh sit amet tincidunt auctor.</p>

<p>Nulla vulputate scelerisque felis, non varius tortor luctus ut. Phasellus quis feugiat est. In eleifend consequat ex in cursus. Quisque sodales dolor vel maximus ullamcorper. Cras mollis turpis ut risus accumsan, ac ornare quam elementum. Curabitur faucibus
  nulla sed mi blandit, et ultrices sem porttitor. Proin quis malesuada turpis, quis cursus nisl. Morbi auctor ante ut efficitur imperdiet.</p>
```

**EDIT:**
In case someone else needs this, I ended up using the following jQuery:

```
<script>
    $('button-class').on('click', function() {
      $(this).children().toggleClass('active');
      $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
      $('#content').toggleClass('active-content');
    });
    </script>
```

And just added the active class, like

```
#sidebar.active {
  //styles here
}

#content.active-content {
  //styles here
}
```

Comment: Are you ok with using JS or does it have to be bootstrap?

Comment: Well if it's easier than editing bootstrap, then yes. Anything will do. :)

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to look at this **[link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp)** since there is a lot of alternatives to use.

In here you can see that it uses this function in the JS

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}
```

In this case, since you are doing it from right to left, you can use style.marginRight. Also, you can adjust the width pixels according to what you have set.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, Squish. This helped. I just don't know how to customize it so that the close/open sidebar is done with just one button. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I do, you can change the function call with javascript document.getElementById("something").onclick = myFunction(); @Retros